# What do I need to configure to get new Instance of JaxbContent object in a Tomcat project

Tags: xml, eclipse, tomcat, jaxb, java-6

I need to unmarshal a xml in a Tomcat server. I already achive it in local, but ones I start my tomcat server it doesn´t work. I´m using JDK 1.6 _115

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(InvoiceType.class.getPackage().getName());
```

throwing an exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:878)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:128)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:249)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:244)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName
    at javax.xml.namespace.QName.<init>(QName.java:246)
    at javax.xml.namespace.QName.<init>(QName.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.setSchemaContext(MappingsGenerator.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateDescriptor(MappingsGenerator.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateProject(MappingsGenerator.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.generateProject(Generator.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:876)
```

I already try using eclipselink 2.5 and 2.6

I expected not exceptions to be able of do unmarshal
like this:

```
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
InvoiceType invoiceType = (InvoiceType) ((JAXBElement) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(isCopy2)).getValue();
```

it works in local

Comment: With what versions did you marshal that data in the first place? And when you were successful and unmarshalling?

Comment: What version of What? Like I say before, I´m able to unmarshal when i´m not using tomcat server, it means running my own main test class in local. "isCopy2" is an ImputStream from the xml file.

Comment: `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext` is the one with problem, this class is contained in a jar usually called eclipselink or moxy. I´m trying with 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2 and 2.6.0 ( this one seem to be for jdk 1.7)